# Setting button location on a webpage

Tags: html

I'm messing around with some chrome extensions and I'm having some issues setting a button location. I've looked at other solutions and they say to use the .display="inline-block"; but that doesn't seem to be working for me. I originally wanted the button the be in the middle.

```
var f = document.getElementById("main");
var myButton = document.createElement('button');
myButton.setAttribute('id','btn');
myButton.innerHTML="Start";
myButton.style.padding="0";
myButton.style.background="#60C22D";
myButton.style.fontSize="10px";
myButton.style.width="40px";
myButton.style.display="inline-block";
myButton.style.textAlign="center";
```

That might not be the best way to set the parameters but as you can see from the images, those values are being called. Is there a way I can call out a specific location of the button? For instance, I want it right below the "Google Search" button, is that possible?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a "position" property in css, it can have different values:

1. absolute
2. relative
3. static
4. fixed
5. sticky
   and...

These have different uses and you can read about them in:

1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
2. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

in this case, absolute or fixed are what you need.

**Note**:also care about z-index

Also if you want to center an element, you can do this:

```
<!--for example we center a div inside its parent-->
   <div id="container">
   <div style="position:absolute;top:50%;left:50%;transform:translate(-50%,-50%)"></div>
</div>
```

Positioning a big subject for beginners

Comment: your 2nd link was the one that had my solution!